# Twitter4J verify Credentials and catching error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, twitter4j

I have the following code on google appengine to test if twitter credentials are valid using twitter4j

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    String Test = "Testing Twitter4J";
    try {

        ConfigurationBuilder confbuilder  = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        confbuilder.setOAuthAccessToken("A") 
        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("B") 
        .setOAuthConsumerKey("C") 
        .setOAuthConsumerSecret("D"); 
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(confbuilder.build()).getInstance(); 

        //Status status = twitter.updateStatus("Working lunch today");
        User user = twitter.verifyCredentials();
        Test = "Successfully updated the status to [" + user.getScreenName() + "].";

    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        Test =  "no";
    }
    try {
        resp.getOutputStream().write(Test.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return;
}
```

If the credentials are valid it works as expected.  If I revoke access so the credentials are not valid I get an app engine error:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
twitter4j.TwitterRuntimeException: 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.
message - Invalid or expired token
code - 89

Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=93f2523c or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=8b74a4e3
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[93f2523c-8b74a4e3], statusCode=401, message=Invalid or expired token, code=89, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.3}
```

from the "User user = twitter.verifyCredentials();" line.  I was expecting the TwitterException to be thrown from the javadoc at:
http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/UsersResources.html#verifyCredentials()
but it seems I get a TwitterRuntimeException.  Why?  I can't find any notes of a TwitterRuntimeException in the javadocs.

Comment: Hiii,,,, HAve you find solution for that?? @Michael..

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was the following:

- Go to your [twitter app](https://dev.twitter.com/apps)
- Select the settings tab
- Under Application Type - Access - Select the last option **Read,Write
  and Access direct messages**

If this doesn't solve the problem try adding Callback URL. You can put any url here it will be fine.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Adding a callback url was my missing piece